# android: Adding external JAR file in to android

Tags: android, jar, external

We are making an application that needs to convert one file format to another.
I am not sure whether we can add a JAR file in which we develop the code to convert the file format to our required file format, to our android project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to create a folder called libs in your main project directory and add any jar that you want to use to this folder. If during testing on the emulator you get a class not found exception or something like that you may add the jar in the order and export tab of your build path configuration.

Comment: create a Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/json/rpc/commons/TypeChecker;
Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/json/rpc/commons/TypeChecker;